# How to integrate Git + Github + Google Drive?

Tags: git, github, google-drive-api

I am running Git on two computers, machine A (OS X) and machine B (Windows 10), while remote hosting on Github. My local working directories for both machine A and B are synced with Google Drive.

I noticed the other day that any time I make a commit on machine A (even when no changes occurred), machine B all of the sudden has modified files which need to be staged and committed.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README.md
        modified:   helper_scripts/scriptA.py
        modified:   helper_scripts/scriptB.py
        modified:   helper_scripts/scriptC.py
        modified:   helper_scripts/scriptD.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Once I run the following on machine B,

```
git add .
git commit -m 'some message'
```

I get the following message on machine B:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I check `git status` on machine A, and the whole process repeats again and again ... This appears to be unusual behavior because I am not making any changes to the files. I hypothesize that Google Drive syncing is causing the issue somehow.

How can I get Git, GitHub and Google Drive to play nice together so as to avoid this vicious cycle I seem to be caught in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't.

It's only a matter of time before your git repo get corrupted and you will lose your work. Seriously, find a better way to backup your work.

Comment: This comment is surely correct if the user is actually trying to run Git on machines A and B. But maybe the user could get some of the benefits they're looking for (which I think is just local availability of files on machines A and B) if they were willing to treat machine A as canonical and only run Git on machine A. Machine A would sync bidirectionally with Github via Git. Changes made on machine B would get replicated on machine A by Google Drive, and the user would then run Git on machine A to sync with Github. This avoids the user's circular Git problems (Git doesn't run on machine B).

Comment: @user3208862 That's my use case, as machine A is my local computer (where I write the code) and B is a server where the code is being run. Since I cannot test that code on A and I'm constantly adding/testing new things, it isn't worth having to run commit&push 50+ times a day, which I do for working code only.

Answer (score 1):

First double-check the nature of the diff reported in machine B (Windows)

Try again with a fresh synchronized repo, but this time done *after* having first typed (on Windows)

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

That will prevent Git doing some automatic modification to files in order to change the eol style (LF vs. CFRL end of lines)