# Is it possible to sync local Github Repository between multiple machines?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am curious if it is possible to sync a local github directory between multiple machines. This does not seem to be possible with google drive stream. Is there an alternative? I'd like to avoid having to commit and push changes when moving between separate systems, because I do this frequently and many times before the code is stable. Others also have access to the github repository.

Comment: Is this using the same account or multiple accounts? What is the error message that you are seeing? Theoretically, you should not be seeing an issue as the whole idea of git and GitHub is that you can work on multiple systems at the same time.

Comment: Why not use i.e. rsync to sync the local repo between hosts?

Comment: I only use one github account, but I transition working between three different computers and primarily use google file stream to sync files between them. I have tried cloning the repo to my google drive and using the matlab source control with git, but whenever I push I get an long hexidecimal error code. 

I read in other threads that it is ill advised to use google drive, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642271/how-to-integrate-git-github-google-drive. I will take a look at rsync.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can move code machine to machine without using the server like you are describing. A word of advice though, if you are not already, you should be creating feature branches. Effectively using feature branches will eliminate some of the issues you are describing.

See "Git - Branches in a Nutshell"
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

You've got your master branch that (ideally) only has working, tested, peer reviewed code. If you are making frequent, iterative changes for a new feature, you should doing it in a feature branch. You can push up changes to the feature branch as often as you like without interrupting what the others who also have access to the github repository are working on, and merge it into your master branch in one go once you know it is stable.

Comment: Yes I employ branches. It is more a convenience of having a fluid experience between each system since I am only concerned about version control with the master branch.